Movie name where a blind girl regains her eyesight
I had seen an English black and white movie several years ago. 
The plot is roughly this. A blind girl(protagonist) falls in love with a man but the man's ex lover/ family friend hates her and tries to kill her. 
One example being that they all go bathing into the sea and she lures the protagonist towards a rocky place, hoping she will crash and die. 
However the fiance saves her. Then the protagonist has an operation whereby she regains her eyesight. However she does not tell anyone about this. She goes back to the fiance's house where the villain(the ex lover) tries to kill her again. 
In the end of course good reigns and the bad girl dies in a car crash or something. 
I believe it's an old movie -- possibly before the 60s. 

This is Madness of the Heart from 1949 with Margaret Lockwood.

Lydia Garth meets Paul de Vandiere, a French nobleman, but their romance is plagued by Lydia's complaint of recurring spells of blurred vision. Paul leaves for France, promising to return and marry Lydia, but she loses her sight while he is gone. Given no hope of recovery, she enters a convent and quickly finds that she has no vocation for life in a nunnery. She finally marries Paul, but encounters strong opposition from Verite Faimont, a neighbor who is very fond of Paul. The latter constantly plots against Lydia and is successful in temporarily breaking up the marriage, but can a miracle of restored vision be seen?

Verite lures her to the rocks when they go out for a swim, and later tries to kill her again, but Lydia, having her eyesight secretly restored, can now see Verite's deadly trap and confronts her about it. Verite eventually dies in a car crash. The entire movie is currently available on Youtube here.

